# Understanding the proof of completeness of $C_{[a,b]}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $\{f_n(t)\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in the function space $C_{[a,b]}$. Therefore, given any $\epsilon >0$, there is an $N_\epsilon$ such that

$$
\left| f_n(t)-f_{n'}(t)\right|<\epsilon
$$
for all $n,n'>N_\epsilon$.

1. It follows that the sequence $\{f_n(t)\}$ is uniformly convergent.
2. The limit of a uniformly convergent sequence of continuous functions is itself a continuous function. Hence, $C_{[a,b]}$ is complete.

**My Problem:** My problem is in understanding $(1)$. How can we conclude that $\{f_n(t)\}$ is uniformly convergent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, $\{f_n(t)\}_{n \geq 0}$ can't be a Cauchy sequence in $C[a,b]$, because its terms are numbers. Let's do a sketch. Take $\{f_n\}_{n \geq 0}$ a $\|\cdot\|_\infty$-Cauchy sequence in $C[a,b]$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. There exists $n_0  > 0$ such that: $$\begin{align} \|f_n-f_m\|_\infty &< \epsilon,\quad \forall\,m,n>n_0 \\ \sup_{a \leq t \leq b}|f_n(t)-f_m(t)| &< \epsilon,\quad\forall\,m,n>n_0 \\ |f_n(t)-f_m(t)|&<\epsilon,\quad \forall\,m,n>n_0,\quad\forall\,t\in[a,b] \end{align}$$So fixed $t$, $\{f_n(t)\}_{n \geq 0}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb R$ (or $\Bbb C$, whatever), and hence it converges. Denote $f(t) = \lim_n f_n(t)$. The proof goes on proving that $f_n \stackrel{\|\cdot\|_\infty}{\longrightarrow}f$. We have that $f$ is continuous, by $(2)$. A good reference is Kreyszig's Introductory Functional Analysis. Can you go on?

---

Well, I came so far, might as well prove that $f_n \stackrel{\|\cdot\|_\infty}{\longrightarrow}f$. Let $\epsilon > 0$.  There exists $n_0  > 0$ such that: $$\begin{align} \|f_n-f_m\|_\infty &< \epsilon,\quad \forall\,m,n>n_0 \\ \sup_{a \leq t \leq b}|f_n(t)-f_m(t)| &< \epsilon,\quad\forall\,m,n>n_0 \\ |f_n(t)-f_m(t)|&<\epsilon,\quad \forall\,m,n>n_0,\quad\forall\,t\in[a,b] \\ \lim_{m \to +\infty}|f_n(t)-f_m(t)| &\leq \epsilon,\quad\forall\,n>n_0,\quad \forall\,t \in [a,b] \\ |f_n(t)-f(t)|&\leq \epsilon,\quad\forall\,n>n_0,\quad \forall\,t\in[a,b] \\ \sup_{a \leq t \leq b}|f_n(t)-f(t)|&\leq \epsilon,\quad\forall\,n>n_0 \\ \|f_n-f\|_\infty &\leq  \epsilon,\quad\forall\,n>n_0\end{align}$$